# How to center table on page?. Center and centering not working

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx, center

I am trying to center the following table. I have tried using \center and \centering after \begin{table} but it do not work. This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\section{table of model and predictions}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering    
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\hline
                              &  &                                            &  &                                                      \\
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Hidden Variable}                                                                                                     \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}          &  &                                            &  &                                                      \\ \hline
                              &  &                                            &  &                                                      \\
\textbf{Equations of motions} &  & Correct                                    &  & Rediscovered                                         \\
\textbf{}                     &  &                                            &  &                                                      \\ \hline
Saddle-Node                   &  & t                                          &  & $0.8*t + 2e-10*t^2 + 10e-4*t^3$                      \\
                              &  &                                            &  &                                                      \\
                              &  & $4\sin(t) + 9.42$                          &  & $0.17*t -2*10^{-2}*t^2+8*10^{-3} + 3.89 sin(t) + 12$ \\
Hopf                          &  & $-t+t^2-t^3$                               &  & $12.99t   -0.8t^2 +   1.06t^3$ cualitatively good    \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: This image contains the output of the non-centered table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your table is **too wide** to put in the line, so it spans to the margin. You can see:

[image: Result]

So you need to make adjustments to the table or change the page settings.

> BTW, your empty line and column are also not recommendable which should be replaced by setting row and column separation.

#### EDIT

If you do want to keep this wide table, you can use `\centerline`,

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\section{table of model and predictions}

\centerline{
    \begin{tabular}{lllll}
    \hline
                                  &  &                                            &  &                                                      \\
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{Hidden Variable}                                                                                                     \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}          &  &                                            &  &                                                      \\ \hline
                                  &  &                                            &  &                                                      \\
    \textbf{Equations of motions} &  & Correct                                    &  & Rediscovered                                         \\
    \textbf{}                     &  &                                            &  &                                                      \\ \hline
    Saddle-Node                   &  & t                                          &  & $0.8*t + 2e-10*t^2 + 10e-4*t^3$                      \\
                                  &  &                                            &  &                                                      \\
                                  &  & $4\sin(t) + 9.42$                          &  & $0.17*t -2*10^{-2}*t^2+8*10^{-3} + 3.89 sin(t) + 12$ \\
    Hopf                          &  & $-t+t^2-t^3$                               &  & $12.99t   -0.8t^2 +   1.06t^3$ cualitatively good    \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \vspace{1em}
}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

which yields
[image: New Result]